# How can I plot the complex function in 2D?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, computational-complexity

My function:

$$sin(wt-jT) \tag{1}$$

where $j$ - complex unit, $T=0.1,\ w=8 \pi,\ t=[0,0.01,0.02..100]$

I transform it to function with real arguments:

$$\sin(wt)\cosh(T)+j\cos(wt)\sinh(T) \tag{2}$$

Then I calculate module:

$$\sqrt{|\sin(wt)cosh(T)|^2+|\cos(wt)sinh(T)|^2} \tag{3}$$

And plotted it together:

1. real part      :$\sin(wt)\cosh(T)$
2. imaginary part :$\cos(wt)\sinh(T)$
3. their module   :$(3)$

I want to know the module $(3)$ correspond to graphical representation of the function $(1)$ or not?

My output:

[image]